# Explain Cohen's kappa in a simplest way?

Tags: cohens-kappa

I'm learning statistics but don't really understand the result of kappa value posted in the first sample [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)

Is there anyone help me explain in English what the value 0.915 means? (observed proportionate agreement) and the kappa value 0.801. Does 0.915 is the value that both A and B agree with the totally 94 proposals? Or something?

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

This appears to be a [tag:self-study] question.  If that is the case, please read our [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and tag your question as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just added "self-study" tag.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard This is asking about the meaning of various Kappa values, which although a simple question, is not covered in the link to another question provided.

Comment: @usεr11852 I suppose, but I don't like the answers there either; too much wind for too little in the sails. If you want to close this question, I think my simple answer would need porting over, see below.

Comment: @usεr11852 Oh, bother.  So fully go there and vote please: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4690/proposal-to-merge-cohens-kappa-q-a/4692#4692

Comment: @Tavrock This is NOT a self-study question. Self-study tag is for routine textbook/lecture exercises. This is not an exercise. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

$$\kappa=\frac{p_o-p_c}{1-p_c}$$
where $p_o$ is the percent observed agreement and $p_c$ is the percent chance agreement (estimated).

The interpretation of a kappa coefficient (Cohen's or otherwise) is the amount of observed non-chance agreement divided by the possible amount of non-chance agreement. So if you correctly classified 80% of the items, but we would expect you to have gotten 20% of them correct by chance alone, then you would have a kappa value of $0.75$ which is smaller than observed agreement (i.e., 80%).

$$\kappa=\frac{0.80-0.20}{1-0.20}=\frac{0.60}{0.80}=0.75$$